# combinations and order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

question as follows : there is a farmer that orders 50 rakes and 6 of them are defective.

sub question is how many ways we can select a set of 50 rakes
For that i put 50*49*48*47*46= 25451200

now how can we select a set of 5 non defective rakes?
how many ways can we select a set of 5 rakes containing 3 defective rakes?
how many ways can select a set of 5 rakes that has at least 2 defective rakes?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean 'how many can we select a set of $5$ rakes' in your first question?

Comment: i was thinking 44C5 for the first one ..

Comment: @fimpellizieri and yes sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose $5$ non-defective rakes, notice that there are a total of $44$ non-defective rakes, meaning that the number of ways to select $5$ of them is
$$_{44}C_5=\frac{44!}{39!5!}$$

To choose $5$ rakes of which $3$ are defective, we will need to select $2$ non-defective rakes from $44$ total and $3$ defective rakes from $6$ total. Thus there are $_{44}C_2$ ways to pick the non-defective rakes and $_6C_3$ ways to pick the defective ones, so there are a total of
$$_{44}C_2\cdot_6C_3=\frac{44!6!}{2!42!3!3!}$$

Finally, we must find the number of ways to pick $5$ rakes, *at least* two of which are defective. Thus there could be $2$, $3$, $4$, or $5$ defective rakes out of your chosen $5$. Using the same method we used for the previous question, the number of ways to have $5$ rakes $2$ of which are defective is
$$_{44}C_3\cdot_6C_2$$
if three are defective, we have
$$_{44}C_2\cdot_6C_3$$
if four are defective,
$$_{44}C_1\cdot_6C_4$$
and if all five are defective,
$$_6C_5$$
and so the total number of ways is
$$_{44}C_3\cdot_6C_2+_{44}C_2\cdot_6C_3+_{44}C_1\cdot_6C_4+_6C_5$$

If you have trouble understanding any of this, just ask and I'll happily explain!